# A Gitlab "import in progress" never ends

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I was importing a Gitlab project from another repository to this new one, but for three days I see a message "Import in progress" and it never ends. I am not able to find any options to delete this repo as well. Has anyone come across a similar situation and knows how to delete this repo?

Comment: Hi, please don't add [solved] in the title again - we don't do that here. We ask that answers go in the answer box, not in questions or in comments. I have added it for you on this occasion.

Answer (score 16):

*(Answer added on behalf of the OP)*.

Just click on the project and select the other settings from the left hand panel at the bottom. (Note: the usual settings available on the right top corner of the page will not be visible since the project is broken due to a bug in importing in gitlab). Then you can delete the project and recreate it again.

Comment: I've noticed you polishing a few of my answers and appreciate it. Q: Why are many of your answers Community Wiki's? I can see the reason for this QA obviously, but others have merit without need for the community wiki.

Comment: Hi @JeremyThompson, you're most welcome for the edits. 99% of my CW answers are written by the question author, and were merged into the question as an "Update" section. Since we like Q/A to be separated here, I roll back the question to the last good question state, and then re-post the answer in the answer section. Sometimes I will offer to the author that they can post under their own name (so I can delete the CW) but they rarely take me up on it.

Comment: I expect I have a few CW that are not in the above category, but they will be very few in number.

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#cancel-import-of-a-project-from-github) (December 2022) proposes a new option:

> ### Cancel import of a project from GitHub
>
> When importing GitHub projects into GitLab, you could not cancel an import that was in progress.
>
> You can now cancel imports from GitHub that are pending or in progress.
> If the import has already started, the imported files are kept.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/247325).

Once canceled, the project can be deleted.